# Anyway to block the user 'xiguai' from creating more accounts, reduce spam?

Tags: discussion

Anyway to block the user [xiguai](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=reputation&search=xig) from creating more accounts and posting spam?

[image]

Comment: If the user is using the same IP address, Then the moderators can ban him. The user is perhaps using a proxy. That's much harder to deal with.

Comment: User is using multiple IPs , I have destroyed few of his accounts before too and did few more today after this meat

Comment: I've seen that we always pick accounts and discuss about them on Meta which I don't think is a good idea, this is a spam case but still, it's like public shaming a user. It's best if you flag a random post on the website or ping the moderator in chat room and discuss about this.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I agree, in general, we shouldn't pick on a user. But this is a special case. Everyone here keeps seeing a new spam post from this user, I flagged his Q's several times but they keep showing over and over. I thought meta is a place to discuss such things than pinging all 3 mods. in a chat. The post also tells other users that mods are already looking into it if others were wondering just like me.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Any idea why the user's accounts (some of them) keep showing when I click on the link in my Qn? Do they remain for a while before being deleted from the system?

Comment: @sv. Because I didn't deleted them, as none of them posted any spam yet. Rest are all gone

Comment: @AnkitSharma Ok. Wasn't sure what's really going on. Isn't it obvious they are created by the same user?

Comment: But not doing any harm either